# Why "some As are Bs" is $\exists x(A(x) \land B(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Lets say we have an English sentence:

> some $A$s are $B$s

We define some predicates:

$A(x)$ is "$x$ is $A$" 
$B(x)$ is "$x$ is $B$"

Then to me , it seems like that there are two possible translations (point me if I am wrong)

1. $\exists x(A(x) \to B(x))$
2. $\exists x(A(x) \land B(x))$

In "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , under exercise 2.7 , they have chosen the second translation.Does that mean the first translation is wrong.If it is wrong , can someone explain to me why it is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no $A$s at all in the world, then $A(x)$ is false for every $x$.
In particular, if we suppose that there is at least one possible value of $x$,
choose a value for $x$ and then $A(x)$ is false.

If $A(x)$ is false then $A(x) \rightarrow B(x)$ is true.

So in the world described above, $\exists x(A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$ is true,
but no $A$s are $B$s for the simple reason that there are no $A$s.

---

Another example, a little less extreme:
suppose there is an $x$ which is a $B$ but not an $A$.
Then this $x$ is a witness for the true statement
$\exists x(A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$.
And this statement will continue to be true even if there are no $A$s that also are $B$s.

---

Another way to look at it
(a heuristic, intuitive approach rather than a rigorous one):
if some $A$s are $B$s,
consider one of those $A$s which is a $B$:
that thing is also a $B$ which is an $A$.
So from "some $A$s are $B$s" it follows that "some $B$s are $A$s",
and vice versa.
This should lead us to expect a symmetric statement;
$\exists x(A(x) \land B(x))$ is such a statement, but
$\exists x(A(x) \rightarrow B(x))$ is not

Comment: Also "Some As are Bs" says: "There do be a thing which is an A and a B."

Comment: @GrahamKemp I mention such a thing in passing in my third argument, though admittedly I gloss over it.

Comment: So , If I translate "All $A$s are $B$s" , then the translation $(\forall x)(A(x) \to B(x))$ will be wrong?

Comment: No, that translation is correct. It's true in any world where there are no $A$s (in which case "All $A$s are $B$s" is vacuously true), as well as some worlds where some $A$s exist.